# Is it possible to compile an Angular library as a web component reusable in different framworks?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I'm currently building an Angular library using `ng g library`.

I'd really like to be able to compile it to use the final component to work with any or no framework at all, so I'd like to convert it into a regular web component.

It is using its own service, directives, pipes etc.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi iam also looking the same , did u find any solution please share us

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) or [Stencil](https://stenciljs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You can of course package your library into an npm package and reuse it wherever you want. just build it and publish it.

Also note that you have to be logged in to npm in order to publish stuff.

And also note that what you publish is public unless you are paying for private packages or using something other than npm repos

```
ng build my-lib
cd dist/my-lib
npm publish
```

Comment: Indeed that's the final goal. But the trick here is that I'd like my library to work outside angular as well, which is why I want to compile it into a regular web component

Comment: Kind of what's done here except I work in a library not in an angular project. Not sure if it makes a difference: https://medium.com/@patrick1729/how-to-create-angular-6-custom-elements-web-components-c88814dc6e0a

Comment: a library is in fact a regular component.
https://codeburst.io/how-to-built-npm-ready-component-library-with-angular-a812a22dc1d5

Comment: Definitely, I just wonder if I can compile the lib directly without compiling the project like int he link I mentioned above. Isn't it a little hacky?